# Use low-res thumbnails to click/view full or large image

Tags: javascript, onclick, thumbnails

I found (here, I think) a nice compact javascript function that very nicely allows a user to click on a small picture to view a full/larger version of the same image.  The problem is the fact that the small images are actually just css-styled (e.g. height limited to 100px) copies of the same image file...this means if I have a lot of potential images in a set, it takes a long time to load these "thumbnails" (as they are not really small file-size thumbnails).

Here is a snippet of the code I am using:

```js
var lastImg = 1; //Set initial thumbnail and preview
document.getElementById(-1).src = document.getElementById(lastImg).src;
document.getElementById(lastImg).className = "thumb";

function preview(img) {
    document.getElementById(lastImg).className = "thumb";
    img.className = "thumb";
    document.getElementById(-1).src = img.src;
    lastImg = img.id
}
```

```css
.preview {width: 100%;}
.thumb {margin:2px; height:100px; float:left;}
```

```html
<img id="0" class="thumb" src="photos/1406960_00.jpg" alt="thumb0" onclick="preview(this);" />
<img id="1" class="thumb" src="photos/1406960_01.jpg" alt="thumb1" onclick="preview(this);" />
<img id="2" class="thumb" src="photos/1406960_02.jpg" alt="thumb2" onclick="preview(this);" />
<img id="3" class="thumb" src="photos/1406960_03.jpg" alt="thumb3" onclick="preview(this);" />
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<img  id="-1" src="photos/1406960_00.jpg" class="preview" alt="default first image" />
```

I would like the src in the class thumb images to actually used the lower res files that I can keep in a thumbs/ directory but then have the onclick event display the larger size image that exists in photos/ into the class preview image.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have figured out a solution:

```
<img id="0" class="thumb" src="thumbs/1406960_00.jpg" name="photos/1406960_00.jpg" alt="thumb" onclick="preview(this);" />
```

If I add the tag "name" to the code for each of the thumbnail images and give the value as the directory/name for the larger file, THAT will be displayed in the target (preview) window onclick: instead of having the script use img.src, use img.name. (document.getElementById(-1).src = img.name;)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var lastImg = 1; //Set initial thumbnail and preview
    document.getElementById(-1).src = document.getElementById(lastImg).src;
    document.getElementById(lastImg).className = "thumb";

    function preview(img) {
        document.getElementById(lastImg).className = "thumb";
        img.className = "thumb";
        document.getElementById(-1).src = img.name; //<-this seems to work
        lastImg = img.id
    }
</script>
```